# Virtual environment are not activated

Tags: python

My OS is Ubuntu.
I installed Python 3.11. I installed python3.11-venv.
I've created venv using `python3.11 -m venv venv`.
Activate script exists.
I run `. venv/bin/activate`. And nothing happens.
Any ideas?

More than this I tried older versions of python that have been already installed in my pc. And the problem is the same. But when I try to activate virtual environment of my old projects it works

**Bash for new project:**

```bash
konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~$ cd backend/

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/backend$ python3.11 -m venv venv

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/backend$ cd venv/

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/backend/venv$ cd bin/

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/backend/venv/bin$ . activate

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/backend/venv/bin$ ls

activate      activate.fish  pip   pip3.10  python3

activate.csh  Activate.ps1   pip3  python   python3.10

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/backend$ . venv/bin/activate

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/backend$
```

**Bash for old project:**

```bash
konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/Dev/ZM$ cd venv

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/Dev/ZM/venv$ cd bin

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/Dev/ZM/venv/bin$ . activate

pyenv-virtualenv: version 'system' is not a virtualenv

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/Dev/ZM/venv/bin$ cd ..

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/Dev/ZM/venv$ cd ..

konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/Dev/ZM$ . venv/bin/activate

(venv) konstantin@konstantin-GA-78LMT-USB3-R2:~/Dev/ZM$
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: try the answer given by @clarkchuni

Comment: I expect (venv) in the beginning of bash string

Comment: How do you activate (successfully) the virtual environment of your old projects? How does it fail for the new ones? Please answer these questions by copy-pasting the full terminal input and output (don't simplify, don't shorten, don't omit anything, include the shell prompts, the commands you typed and the output you get) to your question.

Comment: I added all terminal information to post

Comment: The virtual environment is active if `which python` shows your venv path instead of your previous global path. If your shell configuration has any sort of "dynamic" prompt definition (using `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `bash`, `precmd` in `zsh`, etc), then that will overwrite the static (`PS1="(venv) $PS1"`) definition used by `activate`.

Comment: @chepner which python3.11 shows global path to python.

Comment: You use Python 3.11, yet your new project shows Python 3.10.  If you really ran `python3.11 -m venv venv` from the `backend/` directory, that can't be the case: it should be 3.11 inside the v-env directory. I'd suggest to remove the v-env and try again.

Comment: Note that you don't show the actual creation of the v-env (from which directory etc) and any resulting output; there may have been warning messages or such.

Comment: @9769953 I added creation of venv to my post. In fact I tried both python 3.11 and python 3.10 and result was the same. For old project I used python 3.10 so there is python 3.10 in venv

Comment: So on the lines after `python3.11 -m venv venv` I still see Python 3.10 from the `ls` command. That can't be the case, or things are severely messed up. What is `python3.11 --version` and `~/backend/venv/bin/python3.10 --version`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reinstalled Ubuntu and everything works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You should have to know the location of virtual environment. Your virtual environment name is venv. So, that, you have to write

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

this works for me, I am also a ubantu user.

Comment: This is the same as OPs `. venv/bin/activate`.

Comment: It does not change something